# MPI_ERR_TRUNCATE: On Broadcast

Tags: c++, mpi, broadcast, openmpi

I have an `int` I intend to broadcast from root (`rank==(FIELD=0)`).

```
int winner

if (rank == FIELD) {
    winner = something;
}

MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Bcast(&winner, 1, MPI_INT, FIELD, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
if (rank != FIELD) {
    cout << rank << " informed that winner is " << winner << endl;
}
```

But it appears I get

```
[JM:6892] *** An error occurred in MPI_Bcast
[JM:6892] *** on communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD
[JM:6892] *** MPI_ERR_TRUNCATE: message truncated
[JM:6892] *** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL: your MPI job will now abort
```

Found that I can increase the buffer size in `Bcast`

```
MPI_Bcast(&winner, NUMPROCS, MPI_INT, FIELD, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Where `NUMPROCS` is number of running processes. (actually seems like I just need it to be 2). Then it runs, but gives unexpected output ...

```
1 informed that winner is 103
2 informed that winner is 103
3 informed that winner is 103
5 informed that winner is 103
4 informed that winner is 103
```

When I `cout` the `winner`, it should be `-1`

Comment: I don't have any problems with the code as written; how do you define FIELD?  Can you post more code; and are you absolutely sure that it's this broadcast that is causing the problem?

Comment: @JonathanDursi, here it is **https://gist.github.com/4039617**

Comment: I hope that after three edits of my answer, the root cause of your problem is now readable and understandable :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is an error early in your code:

```c
if (rank == FIELD) {
   // randomly place ball, then broadcast to players
   ballPos[0] = rand() % 128;
   ballPos[1] = rand() % 64;
   MPI_Bcast(ballPos, 2, MPI_INT, FIELD, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
```

This is a very common mistake. `MPI_Bcast` is a collective operation and it must be called by all processes in order to complete. What happens in your case is that this broadcast is not called by all processes in `MPI_COMM_WORLD` (but only by the root) and hence interferes with the next broadcast operation, namely the one inside the loop. The second broadcast operation actually receives messages sent by the first one (two `int` elements) into a buffer for just one `int` and hence the truncation error message. In Open MPI each broadcast uses internally the same message tag values and hence different broadcasts can interfere with each other in not issued in sequence. This is compliant with the (old) MPI standard - one cannot have more than one outstanding collective operations in MPI-2.2 (in MPI-3.0 one can have several outstanding *non-blocking* collective operations). You should rewrite the code as:

```c
if (rank == FIELD) {
   // randomly place ball, then broadcast to players
   ballPos[0] = rand() % 128;
   ballPos[1] = rand() % 64;
}
MPI_Bcast(ballPos, 2, MPI_INT, FIELD, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```