# Error with MPI_Bcast

Tags: c++, mpi, openmp

I am getting an error with MPI_Bcast (I think it is an old one) I am not sure why this is happening. The error is as follows:

```
An error occurred in MPI_Bcast    
on communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD  
MPI_ERR_TRUNCATE: message truncated      
MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL: your MPI job will now abort
```

The code where it happens is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nbProcs; i++){
    for (int j = firstLocalGrainRegion; j < lastLocalGrainRegion; j++){
        GrainRegion * grainRegion = microstructure->getGrainRegionAt(j);
        int grainSize = grainRegion->getBoxSize(nb);
        double * newValues;
        if (myId == i)
            newValues = grainRegion->getNewValues();
        else
            newValues = new double[grainSize]; 
        MPI_Bcast(newValues, grainSize, MPI_DOUBLE, i, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        if (myId != i)
            grainRegion->setNewValues(newValues);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Your issue might be the same as the one in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13290608/1374437). Show us more code context.

Comment: Also: check that `grainRegion->getBoxSize(nb)` returns equal values in all processes, otherwise you might end up with mismatched values of `grainSize` in the `MPI_Bcast` call.

Comment: Note that the buffer must be the same for all the processes (since you will end up with everyone holding the same thing in the buffer in the end). If you want to send 1 value to all processes, you don't need the whole array.

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible reasons for the error.

The first one is that you have a pending previous `MPI_Bcast`, started somewhere before the outer loop, which did not complete, e.g. in a manner similar to the one in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13290608/mpi-err-truncate-on-broadcast).

The second one is a possible buffer size mismatch because of `grainRegion->getBoxSize(nb)` returning different values in different processes. You can examine the code with a parallel debugger or just put a print statement before the broadcast, for example:

```
int grainSize = grainRegion->getBoxSize(nb);
printf("i=%d j=%d rank=%02d grainSize=%d\n", i, j, myId, grainSize);
```

With this particular output format, you should be able to simply run the output through `sort` and then quickly find mismatched values. Because of the barrier, which is always synchornising (the broadcast might not necessary be so), it is hardly possible for the different calls to `MPI_Bcast` to interfere with one another as in the first possible case.

If it happens so that your data structure is distributed and indeed the correct value of `grainSize` is only availalbe at the broadcast root process, then you should first notify the other ranks of the correct size. The simplest (but not the most efficient) solution would be to broadcast `grainSize`. A better solution would be to first perform an `MPI_Allgather` with the number of grain regions at each process (only if necessary), then perform an `MPI_Allgatherv` with the sizes of each region.