MPI_Bcast not Bcasting
I am running an MPI application on 32 processes.
The stdout of the rank 0 process tgets sent to a separate file for startup error logging, we will call this file STARTUP_ERROR while the stdout of all other processes is sent to a separate logfile.
I am running the Intel ditribution of MPI, version 2021.10.0.
My issue is really simple, i am trying to pass around 3 int's from rank 0, which reads them from a text file.
I will show you the output from this code:
...

int nhb,nor,rnfreq;

if (myrank==0)
{
   find_section("HBC parameters");
   read_line("nhb","%d",&nhb);
   read_line("nor","%d",&nor);
   read_line("rnfreq","%d",&rnfreq);
}

printf("Rank %d: sees\t nhb= %d \t nor= %d \t rnfreq= %d\n", myrank, nhb, nor, rnfreq);
fflush(stdout);

MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Bcast(&nhb,1,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
printf("Rank %d: sees\t nhb= %d \n", myrank, nhb);
fflush(stdout);

MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Bcast(&rnfreq,1,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

printf("Rank %d: sees\t rnfreq= %d \n", myrank, rnfreq);

MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Bcast(&nor,1,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

printf("Rank %d: sees\t nor= %d \n", myrank, nor);
MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

printf("Rank %d: sees\t nhb= %d \t nor= %d \t rnfreq= %d\n", myrank, nhb, nor, rnfreq);

hbc=set_hbc_parms(nhb,nor,rnfreq);
...

Before you scream at me, i know i don't actually need all those barriers and flushes, it's just that i have been fiddling with it for a while trying to understand what's wrong.
If i run this then on the file with the rank 0 output i get:
Rank 0: sees     nhb= 10     nor= 20     rnfreq= 20
Rank 0: sees     nhb= 10 
Rank 0: sees     rnfreq= 20 
Rank 0: sees     nor= 20 
Rank 0: sees     nhb= 10     nor= 20     rnfreq= 20

which is perfectly fine. The other processes however:
Rank 14: sees    nhb= 0      nor= 0      rnfreq= 0
Rank 18: sees    nhb= 0      nor= 0      rnfreq= 0
Rank 24: sees    nhb= 0      nor= 0      rnfreq= 0
Rank 30: sees    nhb= 0      nor= 0      rnfreq= 0
Rank 11: sees    nhb= 0      nor= 0      rnfreq= 0
Rank 15: sees    nhb= 0      nor= 0      rnfreq= 0
Rank 17: sees    nhb= 0      nor= 0      rnfreq= 0
Rank 29: sees    nhb= 0      nor= 0      rnfreq= 0
Rank 1: sees     nhb= 0      nor= 0      rnfreq= 0
Rank 2: sees     nhb= 0      nor= 0      rnfreq= 0
Rank 4: sees     nhb= 0      nor= 0      rnfreq= 0
Rank 5: sees     nhb= 0      nor= 0      rnfreq= 0
Rank 6: sees     nhb= 0      nor= 0      rnfreq= 0
Rank 7: sees     nhb= 0      nor= 0      rnfreq= 0
Rank 10: sees    nhb= 0      nor= 0      rnfreq= 0
Rank 13: sees    nhb= 0      nor= 0      rnfreq= 0
Rank 16: sees    nhb= 0      nor= 0      rnfreq= 0
Rank 20: sees    nhb= 0      nor= 0      rnfreq= 0
Rank 21: sees    nhb= 0      nor= 0      rnfreq= 0
Rank 22: sees    nhb= 0      nor= 0      rnfreq= 0
Rank 23: sees    nhb= 0      nor= 0      rnfreq= 0
Rank 26: sees    nhb= 0      nor= 0      rnfreq= 0
Rank 27: sees    nhb= 0      nor= 0      rnfreq= 0
Rank 31: sees    nhb= 0      nor= 0      rnfreq= 0
Rank 3: sees     nhb= 0      nor= 0      rnfreq= 0
Rank 8: sees     nhb= 0      nor= 0      rnfreq= 0
Rank 9: sees     nhb= 0      nor= 0      rnfreq= 0
Rank 12: sees    nhb= 0      nor= 0      rnfreq= 0
Rank 19: sees    nhb= 0      nor= 0      rnfreq= 0
Rank 1: sees     nhb= 1 
Rank 1: sees     rnfreq= 4936495 
Rank 2: sees     nhb= 1 
Rank 2: sees     rnfreq= 4936495 
Rank 3: sees     nhb= 1 
Rank 3: sees     rnfreq= 4936495 
Rank 4: sees     nhb= 1 
Rank 5: sees     nhb= 1 
Rank 5: sees     rnfreq= 4936495 
Rank 6: sees     nhb= 1 
Rank 7: sees     nhb= 1 
Rank 8: sees     nhb= 1 
Rank 8: sees     rnfreq= 4936495 
Rank 9: sees     nhb= 1 
Rank 9: sees     rnfreq= 4936495 
Rank 10: sees    nhb= 1 
Rank 10: sees    rnfreq= 4936495 
Rank 11: sees    nhb= 1 
Rank 11: sees    rnfreq= 4936495 
Rank 12: sees    nhb= 1 
Rank 12: sees    rnfreq= 4936495 
Rank 13: sees    nhb= 1 
Rank 14: sees    nhb= 1 
Rank 14: sees    rnfreq= 4936495 
Rank 15: sees    nhb= 1 
Rank 15: sees    rnfreq= 4936495 
Rank 16: sees    nhb= 1 
Rank 16: sees    rnfreq= 4936495 
Rank 17: sees    nhb= 1 
Rank 17: sees    rnfreq= 4936495 
Rank 18: sees    nhb= 1 
Rank 18: sees    rnfreq= 4936495 
Rank 19: sees    nhb= 1 
Rank 19: sees    rnfreq= 4936495 
Rank 20: sees    nhb= 1 
Rank 20: sees    rnfreq= 4936495 
Rank 21: sees    nhb= 1 
Rank 22: sees    nhb= 1 
Rank 22: sees    rnfreq= 4936495 
Rank 23: sees    nhb= 1 
Rank 23: sees    rnfreq= 4936495 
Rank 24: sees    nhb= 1 
Rank 24: sees    rnfreq= 4936495 
Rank 25: sees    nhb= 0      nor= 0      rnfreq= 0
Rank 25: sees    nhb= 1 
Rank 26: sees    nhb= 1 
Rank 26: sees    rnfreq= 4936495 
Rank 27: sees    nhb= 1 
Rank 28: sees    nhb= 0      nor= 0      rnfreq= 0
Rank 28: sees    nhb= 1 
Rank 28: sees    rnfreq= 4936495 
Rank 29: sees    nhb= 1 
Rank 29: sees    rnfreq= 4936495 
Rank 30: sees    nhb= 1 
Rank 30: sees    rnfreq= 4936495 
Rank 31: sees    nhb= 1 
Rank 31: sees    rnfreq= 4936495 
Rank 4: sees     rnfreq= 4936495 
Rank 7: sees     rnfreq= 4936495 
Rank 13: sees    rnfreq= 4936495 
Rank 21: sees    rnfreq= 4936495 
Rank 25: sees    rnfreq= 4936495 
Rank 27: sees    rnfreq= 4936495 
Rank 6: sees     rnfreq= 4936495 
Rank 8: sees     nor= 10 
Rank 9: sees     nor= 10 
Rank 15: sees    nor= 10 
Rank 18: sees    nor= 10 
Rank 1: sees     nor= 10 
Rank 4: sees     nor= 10 
Rank 5: sees     nor= 10 
Rank 7: sees     nor= 10 
Rank 10: sees    nor= 10 
Rank 12: sees    nor= 10 
Rank 14: sees    nor= 10 
Rank 16: sees    nor= 10 
Rank 19: sees    nor= 10 
Rank 22: sees    nor= 10 
Rank 23: sees    nor= 10 
Rank 24: sees    nor= 10 
Rank 25: sees    nor= 10 
Rank 2: sees     nor= 10 
Rank 3: sees     nor= 10 
Rank 6: sees     nor= 10 
Rank 11: sees    nor= 10 
Rank 13: sees    nor= 10 
Rank 17: sees    nor= 10 
Rank 20: sees    nor= 10 
Rank 21: sees    nor= 10 
Rank 26: sees    nor= 10 
Rank 28: sees    nor= 10 
Rank 29: sees    nor= 10 
Rank 30: sees    nor= 10 
Rank 31: sees    nor= 10 
Rank 27: sees    nor= 10 
Rank 1: sees     nhb= 1      nor= 10     rnfreq= 4936495
Rank 2: sees     nhb= 1      nor= 10     rnfreq= 4936495
Rank 4: sees     nhb= 1      nor= 10     rnfreq= 4936495
Rank 5: sees     nhb= 1      nor= 10     rnfreq= 4936495
Rank 8: sees     nhb= 1      nor= 10     rnfreq= 4936495
Rank 9: sees     nhb= 1      nor= 10     rnfreq= 4936495
Rank 10: sees    nhb= 1      nor= 10     rnfreq= 4936495
Rank 11: sees    nhb= 1      nor= 10     rnfreq= 4936495
Rank 12: sees    nhb= 1      nor= 10     rnfreq= 4936495
Rank 13: sees    nhb= 1      nor= 10     rnfreq= 4936495
Rank 14: sees    nhb= 1      nor= 10     rnfreq= 4936495
Rank 16: sees    nhb= 1      nor= 10     rnfreq= 4936495
Rank 17: sees    nhb= 1      nor= 10     rnfreq= 4936495
Rank 18: sees    nhb= 1      nor= 10     rnfreq= 4936495
Rank 20: sees    nhb= 1      nor= 10     rnfreq= 4936495
Rank 21: sees    nhb= 1      nor= 10     rnfreq= 4936495
Rank 24: sees    nhb= 1      nor= 10     rnfreq= 4936495
Rank 25: sees    nhb= 1      nor= 10     rnfreq= 4936495
Rank 26: sees    nhb= 1      nor= 10     rnfreq= 4936495
Rank 27: sees    nhb= 1      nor= 10     rnfreq= 4936495
Rank 28: sees    nhb= 1      nor= 10     rnfreq= 4936495
Rank 29: sees    nhb= 1      nor= 10     rnfreq= 4936495
Rank 30: sees    nhb= 1      nor= 10     rnfreq= 4936495
Rank 31: sees    nhb= 1      nor= 10     rnfreq= 4936495
Rank 3: sees     nhb= 1      nor= 10     rnfreq= 4936495
Rank 15: sees    nhb= 1      nor= 10     rnfreq= 4936495
Rank 19: sees    nhb= 1      nor= 10     rnfreq= 4936495
Rank 6: sees     nhb= 1      nor= 10     rnfreq= 4936495
Rank 7: sees     nhb= 1      nor= 10     rnfreq= 4936495
Rank 22: sees    nhb= 1      nor= 10     rnfreq= 4936495
Rank 23: sees    nhb= 1      nor= 10     rnfreq= 4936495

So for some reason that i can't really wrap my head around the integers get completely changed by Bcast and I can't understand why. This prompts the error:
Error in set_hbc_parms [hbc_parms.c] (error no=1):
Parameters are not global
Program aborted

Which means that when he subsequently passes the numbers around in this other function, using MPI_Bcast as well, (i won't post the code of this as to not make the question super long but if you request i can provide) he can see that the numbers are actually different from the nonsensical gibberish he broadcasted earlier.
What is wrong?

what is the values of stack variables if rank != 0?

This question is similar to: local variable initialized to zero in C. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

its unintialized. Initializing it at 0 doesn't change anything, i have tried

https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v4.1/man3/MPI_Bcast.3.php has a notion of error handling. try to check for errors.

Thanks for the heads up, didn't know that.
Had the program print out the error code from Bcast at every step and on every rank, it's always 0

i think the issue is that you are broadcqsting with rank zero, no matter the process that does a broadcast. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13292739/8339821 for explanation.

Nope that's not it i just fdound the error and it was outside the scope of what i posted here.
Basically there was a previous Bcast call, this one too from rank0, which was wrongly placed inside an if(rank==0) bracket.
All processes with rank!=0 went forward and executed subsequent Bcast calls thinking rank0 was sending correct data but Rank0 was actually still executing the old Bcast so that's what he sent. From that point on all Bcast calls were communicating wrong data basically.

What should i do with the question now? is it useful to keep it up or should i remove it since the answer wasn't in the code i posted?

closest thing that i can think of is to close with "caused by the typo".

By default, MPI functions will never return anything else then mpi_success. If an error occurs, the execution aborts. Printing an uninitialized variable is UB. We have recently found that latest compilers will optimize such code in really funny ways. Always make sure that you initialize all your variables before looking at them. Even if MPI states "argument only significant at root rank".
