# Send dynamic array with dynamic size using MPI_Bcast

Tags: c++, mpi

OpenMPI: I want to read a file on the root node and send the contents of that file to all other nodes.
I have found that MPI_Bcast does that :

```
int MPI_Bcast(void *buffer, int count, MPI_Datatype datatype,
    int root, MPI_Comm comm)
```

All the examples that I have found have the `count` value already known, but in my case, the count value is primarily known on the root.  Other [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864075/using-mpi-bcast-for-mpi-communication) say the same call of MPI_Bcast retrieves data on the other nodes.

I've added this:

```
typedef short Descriptor[128];
MPI_Datatype descriptorType;
MPI_Type_contiguous(sizeof(Descriptor), MPI_SHORT, &descriptorType);
MPI_Type_commit(&descriptorType);



 if(world_rank == 0)   {
  struct stat finfo;

  if(stat(argv[1], &finfo) == 0) {
        querySize = finfo.st_size/sizeof(Descriptor);
  }

 {
  //read binary query
  queryDescriptors = new Descriptor[querySize];
  fstream qFile(argv[1], ios::in | ios::binary);
  qFile.read((char*)queryDescriptors, querySize*sizeof(Descriptor));
  qFile.close();

  }
}

  MPI_Bcast((void*)&querySize, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  if (world_rank != 0)
  {
        queryDescriptors = new Descriptor[querySize];
  }
  MPI_Bcast((void*)queryDescriptors, querySize, descriptorType, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

When I call it like this :  `mpirun -np 2 ./mpi_hello_world` it works ok, but when I call it with more than **2**, I get this:

```
mpi_hello_world: malloc.c:3096: sYSMALLOc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
mpi_hello_world: malloc.c:3096: sYSMALLOc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
```

Comment: So issue two broadcasts, the first with the count, the second with the buffer contents.

Comment: You are right, that is a solution. I was wondering if there is a mechanism in MPI for such situations.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but my MPI is getting a bit rusty.

Comment: Mark is right - the only solution is to use two broadcasts. Unlike with regular point-to-point communication, MPI provides no way to probe in advance for broadcast messages. As a matter of fact, that also applies to all collective calls, e.g. `MPI_SCATTER`, `MPI_GATHER`, etc.

Comment: I've used the solution Mark pointed, but I get this error because of the second MPI_Bcast, querySize is 23. I am working on a single node, would that be an issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `qFile.read(...)` is not enclosed in a `if(rank==0){}` test, all processes will read the file. And `queryDescriptors = new Descriptor[querySize];` should be called after the first `MPI_Bcast()` for all processes except 0 : before, `querySize` is meaningless on these processes.

Process 0 must :

- read the number of items
- allocate
- read the array
- broadcast the number of items
- broadcast the array

Other processes must :

- receive the number of items
- allocate
- receive the array

Here is a example of how to read an array of float and use dynamic allocation :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include <mpi.h>
using namespace std;

int main (int argc,  char *argv[])
{
    int rank;
    int size;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    if(rank == 0)
    {
        //creating the file
        ofstream myfile;
        myfile.open ("example.txt", ios::out |ios::binary);
        int nbitem=42;
        myfile.write((char*)&nbitem,sizeof(int));

        float a=0;
        for(int i=0;i<nbitem;i++){
            myfile.write((char*)&a,sizeof(float));
            a+=2;
        }
        myfile.close();    
    }


    //now reading the file
    int nbitemread=0;
    float* buffer;
    if(rank==0){
        ifstream file ("example.txt",  ios::in |ios::binary);
        file.read ((char*)&nbitemread, sizeof(int));
        buffer=new float[nbitemread];
        file.read ((char*)buffer,nbitemread* sizeof(float));
        file.close();
        //communication
        MPI_Bcast(&nbitemread, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Bcast(buffer, nbitemread, MPI_FLOAT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }else{

        MPI_Bcast(&nbitemread, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        //nbitemread is meaningfull now
        buffer=new float[nbitemread];
        MPI_Bcast(buffer, nbitemread, MPI_FLOAT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    }

    //printing...
    cout<<"on rank "<<rank<<" rode "<<buffer[nbitemread/2]<<" on position "<<nbitemread/2<<endl;

    delete[] buffer;
    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Compile it with `mpiCC main.cpp -o main` and run by `mpirun -np 2 main`

Another issue in your code is `MPI_Type_contiguous(sizeof(Descriptor), MPI_SHORT, &descriptorType);`. It should be `MPI_Type_contiguous(sizeof(Descriptor), MPI_CHAR, &descriptorType);`
Here is a piece of code based on yours that should do the trick :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <mpi.h>
using namespace std;

int main (int argc,  char *argv[])
{
    int world_rank;
    int size;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);

    int querySize;


    typedef short Descriptor[128];
    MPI_Datatype descriptorType;
    MPI_Type_contiguous(sizeof(Descriptor), MPI_CHAR, &descriptorType);
    MPI_Type_commit(&descriptorType);


    Descriptor* queryDescriptors;


    if(world_rank == 0)   {
        struct stat finfo;

        if(stat(argv[1], &finfo) == 0) {
            cout<<"st_size "<<finfo.st_size<<" descriptor "<<sizeof(Descriptor)<< endl;
            querySize = finfo.st_size/sizeof(Descriptor);
            cout<<"querySize "<<querySize<<endl;
        }else{
            cout<<"stat error"<<endl;
        }

        {
            //read binary query
            queryDescriptors = new Descriptor[querySize];
            fstream qFile(argv[1], ios::in | ios::binary);
            qFile.read((char*)queryDescriptors, querySize*sizeof(Descriptor));
            qFile.close();

        }
    }

    MPI_Bcast((void*)&querySize, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    if (world_rank != 0)
    {
        queryDescriptors = new Descriptor[querySize];
    }
    MPI_Bcast((void*)queryDescriptors, querySize, descriptorType, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    cout<<"on rank "<<world_rank<<" rode "<<queryDescriptors[querySize/2][12]<<" on position "<<querySize/2<<endl;

    delete[] queryDescriptors;

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry not have mention it, but I mostly do the same. I use mpic++ and mpirun -np 3 main

Comment: I have added more code in my question. Vive la France!

Comment: I wonder if this is an issue because I am running this on a single node ?

Comment: Traiasca Romania ! It should not be an issue, except if the file is really big. Since the whole file is broadcast, there are as many copies as processes ( maybe more for message passing). If your file is 20 times smaller than your RAM, it should not fail. How much is that ratio ? Moreover, if you use a cluster, you may need to specify a memory requirement to your job manager. For [SLURM](https://computing.llnl.gov/linux/slurm/) it could be `#SBATCH --mem 1G`. The default value for this limit is usually low and specifying a higher value could help.

Comment: cat /proc/meminfo says: 2052392 kB and file is: 5888 bytes. I am not yet using a cluster, just mpirun and host parameter.

Comment: I've played with the size of the bytes sent and the number of procs, it seems to be case by the amount I'm sending using MPI_Bcast