# Data passing in MPI loop

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, mpi, broadcast

After I broadcast my final array in rank 0 to all other nodes. It should then back to the loop and all of the nodes have the same array. But in fact, I got the original array instead of the array after broadcasting. I am using MPI to do it. I am sure how to use loop in MPI. I have a program similar to this one. First, I need to deal with some calculation with the array in each node. Then find one array among nodes that I need, then I repeat the step from the beginning and do it again and again. Can anyone help me with it or give me better ways to do it? Thank you to everyone.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    //set array of long double to send
    long double array[4][4]{0}, compenergy=0;
    int size, rank;
    int i, j;
    int rank_lowest_energy, lowrank;
    MPI_Status status;

    struct {
        long double val;
        int rank;
    } energy, lowenergy;

    lowenergy.val = 0;

    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
    // Get the number of processes
    size = MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_size();
    // Get the rank of the process
    rank = MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_rank();

    for (int m = 0; m < 3; ++m)
    {
        //MPI::COMM_WORLD.Bcast(&array, 4*4, MPI::LONG_DOUBLE, 0);
        if (rank == 0) 
        {
            energy.val = 10000;
            energy.rank = rank;
        }
        else
        {
            for (i = 0; i < rank; ++i)
                array[rank][i] += rank;

            energy.val = rank + 10 - array[rank][0]- lowenergy.val;
            energy.rank = rank;
        }

        MPI_Allreduce(&energy, &lowenergy, 1, MPI_LONG_DOUBLE_INT, MPI_MINLOC, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        if (rank == lowenergy.rank)
            MPI::COMM_WORLD.Send(&array, 4 * 4, MPI::LONG_DOUBLE, 0, 0);

        if (rank == 0) 
        {
            MPI::COMM_WORLD.Recv(&array, 4 * 4, MPI::LONG_DOUBLE, MPI::ANY_SOURCE, MPI::ANY_TAG);
            cout << "Its rank is: " << lowenergy.rank << "\n";
            cout<< "Its value is: "<<lowenergy.val<<"\n";
            for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i) 
            {
                for (j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
                    cout << array[i][j] << "  ";
                cout << "\n";
            }
            MPI::COMM_WORLD.Bcast(&lowenergy, 1, MPI::LONG_DOUBLE_INT, 0);
        }
        MPI::COMM_WORLD.Bcast(&array, 4*4, MPI::LONG_DOUBLE, 0);
    }

    MPI::Finalize();
}
```

Comment: please format the code correctly.

Comment: You should not broadcast `lowenergy`

Comment: @ptb Sorry, I do not understand what you mean. Could you please explain it in details?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, if I do not broadcast lowenergy, can I get the value when starts a new loop?

Comment: The formatting has already been corrected.

Comment: Why would you broadcast lowenergy after an allreduce ? If you really want to broadcast , then do it on all ranks (e.g. not only on rank 0). Note lowenergy.rank could directly broadcast array (e.g. no send/recv). Last but not least, your program is incorrect w.r.t. the MPI standard since it might deadlock when lowenergy.rank is 0.

Comment: MPI_Bcast must be called by all processes. You can have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864075/using-mpi-bcast-for-mpi-communication

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet What I want to do is that after I broadcast lowenergy, I need to reuse it to do some calculation in the new loop for each node. And it works. But when I broadcast array at the last line in the loop, it did not work.

Comment: @lmontigny, I think I kind of know what you mean. But in my situation, I can broadcast lowenergy instead of array. According to your advice, I should succeed boradcast array at the last line in the loop rather than lowenergy which is not called by all processes. Is it right?

Comment: @GillesGouaillarde, I want to braodcast both array and lowenergy. Do you have any way to do it? I want the update the array and lowenergy each time staring a new loop.

Comment: @ptb, do you have any advice can give me to help me correct my codes? Thanks.

Comment: `MPI_Allreduce()` has the same outcome than `MPI_Reduce()` followed by `MPI_Bcast()`, so what is the point of broadcasting again `lowenergy` ? Then you can simply `MPI_Bcast(buffer=array, ..., root=lowenergy.rank, ...)`

Comment: I'm not too sure what you are actually trying to do here.  It would helpful if you edit your question to include sample inputs and the expected outcome